# js - change html attribute with a js button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a HTML page to control a thermostat outside home.
I want to use HTML `button` attribute to increase/decrease the values but it doesn't work. What's wrong with my code?

And if you want to use JQuery, please explain easily since I'm new to JS.

Code:

```
<script>
  var heatTemp=21;
</script>

<button class="temp_btn" onClick="heatTemp++">⇧</button>
<button class="temp_btn" onClick="heatTemp--">⇩</button>

<p id="heatset"></p>
<script>
  document.getElementById("heatset").innerHTML = heatTemp;
</script>
```

If it's trivial, sorry but I could't find any tips on this... Sorry again.

Comment: That code should work. But, no, increasing/decreasing the number doesn't change the content of the element.

Comment: `heatTemp++`/`heatTemp--` this will increment/decrement heatTemp but it doesn't automatically update the html, you have to do that manually

Comment: Oh... So does that mean I need a function to update the values?

Comment: You can write it after increment. Something like this: 
heatTemp++; document.getElementById("heatset").innerHTML = heatTemp

Comment: Thanks, guys. I wrote a function(to keep it neat) and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update innerHtml on every click. So I moved the plus and minus to a new function. Also dont forget to Show the initial value of 21 inside #heatset:

```
<script>
  var heatTemp=21;
</script>

<button class="temp_btn" onClick="changeTemp(1)">⇧</button>
<button class="temp_btn" onClick="changeTemp(-1)">⇩</button>

<p id="heatset">21</p>
<script>
function changeTemp(dt){
   heatTemp =heatTemp + dt;
  document.getElementById("heatset").innerHTML = heatTemp;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I did set the initial value, but I didn't include it in the snippet. Anyway it's an answer!

Comment: Just do `heatTemp += dt`. It's shorter.